# How can I add 'email scanned for viruses' to the emails

Tags: email, postfix, amavis

I have a small, Opensuse-based computer for my family, which includes GUI, Postfix, amavis, clamd & spamassassin. I noticed that Amavis adds a line among the hidden headers:

```
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at mycomputer.mydomain.pl
```

Now, I also noticed that some of the incoming emails have similar messages also in the body text, visible to the reader, after the sender's signature.

How can I set up my system to add a similar notification in the body text as well?

Comment: Why do you want to add a notification in the body text?

Comment: So that the addressee can see that the message has been scanned and is (probably) safe - if it really is, of course. Besides, if it also clearly demonstrates that I do care about email safety.